# Is there any way to do "logical" transformations between Japanese kana characters with different diacritical marks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

In Japanese, there are combining diacritical marks that apply to certain *kana*, so there is a logical relationship between say "か" (*ka*) and "が" (*ga*) - the *ga* character is voiced.

I'm wondering if there is any natural way (in Python, preferably, though a generalized answer about unicode is fine, too) to do the equivalent of transforming voiced characters to their unvoiced equivalents, and vice-versa - something akin to the `lower()` method that applies in latin scripts. An example of what I'm looking to do:

```
>>> devoice('が')
"か"
>>> voice('か')
"が"
>>> devoice('か')
"か"
>>> semivoice('は')
"ぱ"
>>> devoice('ぱ')
"は"
```

At the moment, the best approach I seem to be able to come up with is to generate a lookup table indexed by row, column and voicing, then look up the character I have and translate it in the right direction. That said, I'd like to know if there's a more natural way to do it.

One potential pitfall is that it seems to me that the unicode combining characters do not seem to compare equal to their single-codepoint equivalents:

```
>>> a = chr(0x304B) + chr(0x3099)
>>> b = chr(0x304C)
>>> print(a)
'が'
>>> print(b)
'が'
>>> a == b
False
```

I am mainly concerned with the ones that do *not* involve combining diacriticals, since it seems easy enough to detect and strip off the combining marks.

*Note:* I am not sure I understand Japanese phonology well enough to know what the correct behavior is for `う` (u) and `ゔ` (vu - rare / obsolete), which again is why it would be nice if there were a "natural" way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can de-voice by decomposing the character (moving from the NFC to NFD forms), using the [`unicodedata.normalize()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> print(ascii(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', '\u304c')))
'\u304b\u3099'
```

so `devoice()` can be implemented as:

```
def devoice(char):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFD', char)[0]
```

If voicing always adds `\u3099` (which it looks like), you can just add that to the entered kana and return the `NFC` combined normal form:

```
def voice(char):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFC', char + '\u3099')
```

It looks like semivoiced means you add `\u309a'`:

```
def semivoice(char):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFC', char + '\u309a')
```

You could possibly use `unicodedata.decomposition()` to test if there is a decomposition:

```
import unicodedata

def voice(char):
    if not ('\u3041' <= char <= '\u3096') or len(char) > 1 or unicodedata.decomposition(char):
        return char
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFC', char + '\u3099')

def semivoice(char):
    if not ('\u3041' <= char <= '\u3096') or len(char) > 1 or unicodedata.decomposition(char):
        return char
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFC', char + '\u309a')

def devoice(char):
    if not ('\u3041' <= char <= '\u3096') or len(char) > 1 or not unicodedata.decomposition(char):
        return char
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFD', char)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! What about the other direction? I would prefer that `voice('\u304b')` return `'\u304c'`, not `'\u304b\u3099'`.

Comment: Looks good! Thanks. There's still some delay before I can accept an answer.